# INSERT in SQL Server not using blank as default value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm having some problems with a query generated by a program I use. The program make an insert into two different databases on different servers:

```
INSERT INTO Sumas (codeje, codcta, codpercon, impdeb) 
VALUES ('2018', '6311001', 9, -8000)
```

On the first server, the query works fine, but on the other server, I have a problem with a null value. The complete table:

[image]

I assume that if I don't pass the value, one server use the null and the other use blan^k. There is any configuration where I can change this?

Comment: Check default value for each column you don't provide value in `INSERT INTO`: `SELECT COLUMN_DEFAULT, * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Sumas'`

Comment: @Larnu They are the first 4 rows.   It's not the table data, it's a meta table about the table.

Comment: @TabAlleman Doh! I (foolishly) *assumed* that was the user's data, not the table definition. TGI it's Friday. Thanks

Comment: Which field do you have the null value problem on? You might have to show the data from each server to illustrate the problem. The only fields that allow nulls are numeric fields, so what does the "blank" value actually look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the schema for the table and examine the field for a possible default value. If you have the ability to change it, update it so that the two are the same.

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem. With sp_columns sumas I see that in one table the default value was NULL and in the other '' or 0. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you found your answer. Please take a moment to mark this as your accepted answer by clicking the gray check mark to the left of the answer. It lets other users know the question has an answer, and rewards the user who answered with some reputation points.